# Camel sql component cron schedule customization

Tags: sql, apache-camel

As I have looked , camel sql-component is not supporting `cron expressions` but fixed delays etc. I have checked source code of the component but I could not find an easy way to customize it. Is there any other way to make it or should I extend all component, endpoint , consumer and producer in order to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation about polling consumer: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html at the section further below for *scheduled poll consumers*.

You can configure to use a different scheduler such as spring/quartz2 that has cron capabilities.

I blogged about how to do this: http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html but it should work with the sql component also.

Comment: @Clause In sql endpoint, even I write scheduler=spring in uri, at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollEndpoint.configureScheduledPollConsumerProperties(Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>) line 127 , schedulerName is always null. The setScheduler(String) method runs after configureScheduledPollConsumerProperties method so schedulerName is always null at that point :(

Answer (score 1):

I second @Neron's comment above. I believe this is a bug in the camel-sql compnent. I am currently using version 2.16.2, but I don't see any changes in a higher version that would have resolved this.

For those interested, you can work around this by creating a subclass of the SQLComponent like this.

```
public class SQLComponentPatched extends SqlComponent {

    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        Endpoint endpoint = super.createEndpoint(uri, remaining, parameters);

        setProperties(endpoint, parameters);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Claus ? Are we missing something?